# Create a temp table with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, create-table, temp-tables, with-statement

I'm struggling with creating a temporary table with multiple conditions.

Let's call this main table A. I want to pull data from this table to output the distinct account with their last purchase date and payment date to a temporary table.

```
+---+--------+-----------+----------+
|   |  Acct  | Trans_Date|Trans_code|
+---+--------+-----------+----------+
| 1 | ABC    | July 31 | Purchase |
| 2 | ABC    | Nov 5   | Payment  |
| 3 | DEF    | Mar 1   | Purchase |
| 4 | ABC    | June 5  | Purchase |
| 5 | GFH    | Feb 7   | Payment  |
| 6 | GFH    | Mar 9   | Purchase |
| 7 | DEF    | Aug 8   | Payment  |
| 8 | GFH    | Mar 9   | Purchase |
| 9 | DEF    | Aug 8   | Payment  |
+---+--------+---------+----------+
```

Output result

```
+---+-------+----------------+--------------+
|   |  Acct | Last_trans_date|Last_transpay |
+---+-------+----------------+--------------+
| 1 | ABC   | July 31        | Nov 5        |
| 2 | DEF   | Mar 1          | Aug 8        |
| 3 | GFH   | Mar 9          | Feb 7        |
+---+------+-----------------+--------------+
```

I read that using the WITH clauses could be an option, but struggling to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation like so:

```
select acct,
    max(case when trans_code = 'Purchase' then trans_date end) as last_purchase,
    max(case when trans_code = 'Payment'  then trans_date end) as last_payment
from mytable
group by acct
```

The syntax to insert the result of a query to another table varies across databases. In many of them, you can use:

```
create table newtable as 
select ... -- above query
```

SQL Server is a notable exception, where you would need:

```
select ...
into newtable
from ...
group by ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was much easier than I thought.

Answer (score -1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select acct, max(trans_date),
       max(case when trans_code = 'Payment' then trans_date end)
from t
group by acct;
```

You can then insert this into an existing table or use the appropriate mechanism for your database to save the result as a new table.